# googlemap not working on android 4.2

Tags: android

Will running my google map in enumerator  using eclipse my Android version is 4.2 i get a message that u have to update my google service with one button with text Update

LOGCAT

```
    05-19 10:27:43.540: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1744): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4323000 but found 3136130

    05-19 10:27:43.625: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1744): Google Play services out of date.                                              Requires 4323000 but found 3136130



    05-19 10:29:29.780: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1744): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4323000 but found 3136130

       05-19 10:29:29.830: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1744): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4323000 but found 3136130


    05-19 10:29:32.250: D/AndroidRuntime(1744): Shutting down VM



    05-19 10:29:32.250: W/dalvikvm(1744): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)

        05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
          No   Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW     dat=market://details?

     id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source) 


    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)

   05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):  at 

    android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

   05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

  05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):   at 

  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

   05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):  at 

   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

   05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):  at 

   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

   05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):  at 


   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at 

    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

    05-19 10:29:32.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): at        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    05-19 10:29:35.960: I/Process(1744): Sending signal. PID: 1744 SIG: 9
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Android Main Fest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jagmap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <permission  android:name="com.example.jagmap.MAPS_RECEVICE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.jagmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />    
</application>
```

```
MainActivity.java
  package com.example.jagmap;

  import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
   import android.view.Menu;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}*/

  }
```

Comment: have you test in devide?

Comment: what is the value of google_play_services_version ?

Comment: update google play services and try.

Answer (score 1):

The device needs the Google Play Services to be updated. You should actually, check for this error, and prompt the user. This is required for Google Maps to work.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> To verify the Google Play services version, call
>   isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(). If the result code is SUCCESS, then
>   the Google Play services APK is up-to-date and you can continue to
>   make a connection. If, however, the result code is SERVICE_MISSING,
>   SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, or SERVICE_DISABLED, then the user
>   needs to install an update. So, call
>   GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog() and pass it the result error
>   code. This returns a Dialog you should show, which provides an
>   appropriate message about the error and provides an action that takes
>   the user to Google Play Store to install the update.

Answer (score 0):

Emulators are updated less frequently. The image that is used by emulator is built and inmeanwhile if the play services version is upgraded on Google and you have the latest Google play services then this message will show up. Make sure you are using latest Google API image and Google Play services by looking into SDK Manager. If not, then update and try again by creating new emulator with latest image. If you do have the latest google api image and play services and still getting this message, you cannot do much besides testing the map on real device.

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows that in your emulator your play services are not latest, you are supposed to update it by uninstalling and re-install the play store app in your app.

"`Google Play services out of date. Requires 3159100 but ..`"
Below are the updated [gms](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nhea18k7ic2gpb/com.google.android.gms-20130716.apk) and [vending](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hznsfc03shud2l9/com.android.vending-20130716.apk) files.

Create a new emulator with any cpu/abi, a non google-api target (versions 10-17 work) and gpu emulation on or off, and then install the files:

```
adb install com.android.vending-20130716.apk 
adb install com.google.android.gms-20130716.apk
```

If you are upgrading an existing emulator then you might need to uninstall previous versions by:

```
adb uninstall com.android.vending
adb uninstall com.google.android.gms
```

Also check [Thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880#makechanges) of similar issue.

Hope this help you.

Comment: i try to install this apk but i get an error  
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86>cd sd*

C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk>cd p*

C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools>adb install com.android.vending-201
30716.apk
208 KB/s (6040792 bytes in 28.267s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.android.vending-20130716.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools>